# How would you translate "übersichtlich"?

Tags: german-to-english

I often get that word when people describe layouts of digital programs being "übersichtlicher" than others. How would you translate it?

- clear
- lucid
- manageable

These don't really sound right to me.

Comment: Good translations always depend on context. You could mention here a specific sentence (or other context) where you need an adequate translation for "übersichtlich". You should, however, also publish your own solutions (perhaps including some notes about your doubts), as this is what is regarded good practice of asking here in this forum.

Comment: I don't know if "the english ones" have a vague word like "übersichtlicher". With adding context I would also try this question on ELL.SE. "less crowded" can also fit - depends of intention of speaker... - or you reformulate the question to get a better understanding of "übersichtlicher" first - assuming, your mother tongue is not German

Comment: Welcome. It is better to ask for the *meaning* of a German word here. If you ask for a *translation* to another language then the question is likely to be seen as off-topic. Also, you risk getting answers of poorer quality, because even if we often converse in English here, many of us have misconceptions on the nuances of many English words.

Answer (score 3):

I could see **'clear-cut'**, **'readable'** and maybe **'comprehensible'** making sense.

I usually play around with a thesaurus when I have problems like this.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of opinion: I think "übersichtlich" for **clear** is very suitable. But you can also use **comprehensible layout than others** to demonstrate a "verständlicherer Entwurf/Plan".

To say about a layout that is "übersichtlich" than others, you can also use "anschaubar" -> viewable {adj}. Example: "anschaulicher als die anderen Entwürfen/Pläne"